# HOW TO USE IBM WATSON SERVICE IN AN ANGULAR4 PROJECT?

Tags: angular, cloud, cloud-foundry, watson-conversation, watson

I am trying to use the IBM Watson services / APIs in MY ANGULAR 4 project under CLOUD FOUNDRY (CF). But I have not been able to figure out how do I include the service in my application as the node SDK provided by Watson is very confusing. Can anyone help me to setup IBM WATSON with ANGULAR4 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Please don't SHOUT.  It doesn't help you get the kind of attention you want.  It just annoys people.  2) Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) ... and modify (or delete) your question based on that advice.

Comment: for starters, I found this github code that has a basic setup of Watson with angula, but it doesnt seem to be working: https://github.com/adrien2p/watson-sea2

Answer (score 0):

Some APIs do not allow Frontend clients request hence you have to create a backend for your angular4 app then make the API calls to IBM Watson from your backend. In your case, you can create a simple node backend that responses to your angular4 app's requests then make api calls to IBM Watson and responses with data from IBM Watson to your angular4 app.

Comment: Sounds acheivable, but I will need some help on the same. I got a basic setup using the IBM cloud Node SDK :  https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk.git

Comment: but the problem is that I could not add angular 2/4 to it. It would really nice if 

Abdul-Razak Adam, you could help me with it.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  If you need someone to help you, I suggest that you try one of the many rent-a-coder or rent-an-expert sites.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Jain Check this node library out : Watson Developer Cloud Node.js SDK (https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud)